# "et" instead of ampersand "&" for French biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, french

I'm using `BibLaTeX` (APA) in French and I have one little problem:
When I have only two authors, they are cited with the conjunction symbol `&` whereas I would like the grammatical French conjunction term `et`. Here is a part of the code:

```
\RequirePackage[hyperref,backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily} 
 % for avoiding small caps problem
```

Comment: Without having the opportunity to test it right now, I think you could try `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{et}}` or something similar.

Comment: Unless your `biblatex` is horribly outdated, you can (and probably should) drop the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}`.

Answer (score 4):

APA wants "&" instead of "and" in certain situations. If you want all "&"s between names to be "and"s, try the following code

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{%
  \restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily} 

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite,fullcite,fullcitebib]{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
       {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
       {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

ipsum \textcite{sigfridsson}

dolor \parencite{sigfridsson}

sit \nptextcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson et Ryde, 1998) ipsum Sigfridsson et Ryde (1998) dolor (Sigfridsson et Ryde, 1998) sit Sigfridsson et Ryde, 1998]